# System broke, most things aren't opening

Tags: networking, 18.04, package-management, gnome-control-center

In my system many apps are not working the terminal fails to start and Settings disappeared from app menu. I tried searching for the
settings app in file explorer and there's only one option in it.

[image]

I also tried Alt+F2 gnome-control-center but it's showing that command not found.

Also ethernet is connected but unable to access the internet

Edit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMK82.png Also why do these Started column entries look missing?

[image]

Comment: Did you do anything in particular before this happened? If yes, you better explain in detail what you did.

Comment: Not sure about that, sorry. But can I make it work by downloading some system files and pakages in different system and transferring them into their respective directories using USB ??

Comment: I don't remember doing anything but is there any way to restore the missing items, i can't even connect to internet to download any packages.

Comment: you probably messed up your PATH and bashrc config

Comment: Did you change the default python version?

Comment: Can you open a terminal using Ctrl + Alt + F3?

Comment: Yes I changed the python version 2 days ago.